# How to extract text present inside that detected circle using cv2 python. I want only the text present that circle

Tags: python

How to extract text present inside that detected circle using cv2 python. I want only the text present that circle

I have detected the circles from tif image, now i am facing problem with text extraction only from that detected circles.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What OCR engine or model have you tried to use? Have you tried to follow this guide ["OpenCV OCR and text recognition with Tesseract"](https://pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/17/opencv-ocr-and-text-recognition-with-tesseract/)?